# Retreival of multiple row from oracle 10g

Tags: html, jsp, oracle10g

I have created a table in oracle which consist of college_names, student_name,regno and result belong to particular college and college_ids of each and every college and date on which the data has been stored...

Now I want to give college_id and date and i want all the student name with their result and regno in a table like structure in a browser I have written one html page for giving college_id and date and one jsp page for retrieving different fields from database but its not working..here is my code for both the pages..

this is my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org     /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
function check()
{
var a=result.college_id.value;
var b=result.date.value;
if(a==""|| b=="")
{
alert("fill the fields")
}
else
{
result.action="result.jsp";
result.method="post";
result.submit();
}
}

 </script>
 </head>

 <body bgcolor="#cc99ff">
 <form name="result">
 <center>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>college_id:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="college_id"></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>date:</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="date"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <input type="Button" value="Submit" onClick="check()">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now here is my jsp page for retrieving multiple rows...

```
<html>
<body background="main_BG.jpg">
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>
<%!
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;
ResultSet rs;
String college_id;
String college_name;
String regno;
String student_name;
String result;
String date;

%>

<%
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","pro","pro
");

college_id=request.getParameter("college_id");
date=request.getParameter("date");


ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from add_result where college_id=? and date=?");
ps.setString(1,college_id);
ps.setString(6,date);
rs=ps.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
{
college_name=rs.getString(2);
regno=rs.getString(3);
student_name=rs.getString(4);
result=rs.getString(5);
}
else
{
    out.println("no data found");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{

    out.println("<center><b><font color=lightblue>some error occured...please try  again</font></b></center>");
    out.println("<br><br><a href='result.html'><center><b><font color=lightblue>click here to return..</font></b></center>");

}
%>

<center>
<font color=lightblue>
<b>
Information of student with college_id [<%=college_id%>]:
</b>
</font>
</center>
<p style="position:absolute;left:100;top:100">

<table border="2" width="100%">
<th style="color:yellow">
college_name
</th>
<th style="color:yellow">
regno
</th>
<th style="color:yellow">
student_name
</th>
<th style="color:yellow">
result
</th>
<tr>
<td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=college_name%></td>
<td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=regno%></td>
<td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=student_name%></td>
<td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=result%></td>
</tr>

</table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you expand on "not working"?  Do you get an error?  If so, what error?  Does the data not display in the format you expect?  If so, can you describe what you are seeing vs. what you want to see?

Comment: No errors but data is not displaying instead of data null is below all the fields

Comment: So you get an HTML table with multiple rows but all the data is `NULL`?  Or are you stating that the table is missing?

Comment: table is there but all the data is null

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
 try
 {
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","pro","pro   ");

  college_id=request.getParameter("college_id");
  date=request.getParameter("date");
  String sql = "select * from add_result where college_id=? and date=?"; 
  ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setString(1,college_id);
  //ps.setString(6,date);
  ps.setString(2,date);
  System.out.println("Sql: " + sql);
  rs=ps.executeQuery();
  // process resultset below
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {

   out.println("<center><b><font color=lightblue>some error occured...please try again</font></b></center>"); 
   out.println("<br><br><a href='result.html'><center><b><font color=lightblue>click here to return..</font></b></center>");

  }
%>

<center>
<font color=lightblue>
<b>
Information of student with college_id [<%=college_id%>]:
</b>
</font>
</center>
<p style="position:absolute;left:100;top:100">

<table border="2" width="100%">
<th style="color:yellow">
college_name
</th>
<th style="color:yellow">
regno
</th>
<th style="color:yellow">
student_name
</th>
<th style="color:yellow">
result
</th>
<%
 if(rs!=null){
  while(rs.next())
  {
   college_name=rs.getString(2);
   regno=rs.getString(3);
   student_name=rs.getString(4);
   result=rs.getString(5);
%>
 <tr>
  <td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=college_name%></td>
  <td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=regno%></td>
  <td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=student_name%></td>
  <td style="color:lightgreen" align="center"><%=result%></td>
 </tr>
<%
  } // result set loop ends here
 }else{
%>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="4" style="color:red" align="center">No Data Found</td>
   </tr>
<%
 }  //if condition ends here
%>
```

Comment: Still not working table is displaying with null values and your if and while condition is displaying above the table..

Comment: I have done that its working there when we are having only one row but not working for more than one row..

Comment: I have edited answer to print sql on console.But Now I doubt on data type of `date` column. What's that. We are passing string from here

Comment: I am having two rows with college_id=1 and date=20-apr-12

Comment: datatype of date column is date

Comment: @Razia: Now Check value of `date` variable which you are getting from request parameter

Comment: If i m taking datatype of date as date in jsp then its showing error and instead of ps.setString I have change it to ps.setDate

Comment: plzz help this problem is not because of date when i remove the date field completely still the same problem is there data is not displaying......